# NextJS / Mailgun / Amazon S3 - Files uploaded are empty/blank

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, mailgun

I am building a contact form (NextJS), in combination with Amazon S3 and Mailgun.

Basically, it has a few standard input fields + a drag or add file input.

When the user clicks to add a file, it should first get uploaded to Amazon S3, then it should take the link from S3 and attach it to the email.

Now, most of this is working as intended, the files are getting uploaded to S3, then I receive the e-mail, the file name is correct, but the problem is that it's empty, no matter if it's an image, a text file, a pdf file, it's fully blank, both in the e-mail attachment and in the s3 bucket.

**uploadFile.ts** (api/)

```
  const s3 = new S3({
  region: process.env.REGION,
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '10mb',
    },
  },
};

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).json({ message: 'Method not supported' });
  }

  try {
    let { name, type } = req.body;

    let params = {
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
      Key: name,
      Expires: 600,
      ContentType: type,
      ACL: 'public-read',
    };

    const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);

    res.status(200).json({ url });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).json({ message: e });
  }
};
```

}

**handleChange() function which handles the uploading of the files to S3**

```
const handleChange = async (event: any) => {

event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

//This sets the state with the picked file (from click event)
setTheFile(event.target.files[0]);
setTheFileName(event.target.files[0].name);
setTheFileType(event.target.files[0].type);
setUploadedFile(BUCKET_URL + event.target.files[0].name);

let { data } = await axios.post('/api/uploadFile', {
  name: event.target.files[0].name,
  type: event.target.files[0].type,
});

const url = data.url;

await axios.put(url, theFile, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': event.target.files[0].type,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
});

setTheFile(null);
 };
```

**handleSubmit() function which handles the sending of the email itself**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
console.log('sent');
e.preventDefault();
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', theFileName!);

const url = '/api/form';

await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(
    '{"name": ' +
      '"' +
      name +
      '"' +
      ', ' +
      '"subject": ' +
      '"' +
      subject +
      '"' +
      ', ' +
      '"email": ' +
      '"' +
      email +
      '"' +
      ', ' +
      '"message": ' +
      '"' +
      text +
      '"' +
      ', ' +
      '"file": ' +
      '"' +
      uploadedFile +
      '"' +
      '}'
  ),
   });
      };
```

**And the form itself**

```
 {!submitted ? (
        <form
          encType="multipart/form-data"
          ref={form}
          onSubmit={(e: any) => handleSubmit(e)}
          className="flex flex-col py-8 w-full"
        >
          <h2 className="font-light text-2xl mt-8 mb-8">
            Submit your request
          </h2>

          <input
            required
            type="email"
            className="block py-[20px] px-[10px] bg-white rounded-[10px]  border-[2px] border-[#e1e1e1] mb-14"
            placeholder="Your Email..."
            onChange={(e: any) => setemail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            required
            type="text"
            className="block py-[20px] px-[10px] bg-white rounded-[10px]  border-[2px] border-[#e1e1e1] mb-14"
            placeholder="Your Name..."
            onChange={(e: any) => setname(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            required
            type="text"
            className="block py-[20px] px-[10px] bg-white rounded-[10px]  border-[2px] border-[#e1e1e1] mb-14"
            placeholder="Subject..."
            onChange={(e: any) => setsubject(e.target.value)}
          />
          <textarea
            required
            rows={8}
            className="block py-[20px] px-[10px] bg-white rounded-[10px] border-[2px] border-[#e1e1e1] mb-14"
            name="Message"
            placeholder="Your Message..."
            onChange={(e: any) => settext(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
          <input
            type="file"
            className="hidden py-[20px] px-[10px] bg-white rounded-[10px]  border-[2px] border-[#e1e1e1] mb-14"
            ref={hiddenFileInput}
            onChange={(event: any) => handleChange(event)}
          />
          <p className="text-slate-400">
            Accepted format:
            <br /> PDF / WORD / PNG / JPG
          </p>
          <p className="text-red-500">{fileError}</p>
          <button
            onClick={(e: any) => handleClick(e)}
            className="py-[20px] px-[10px] bg-white rounded-[10px] border-[2px] border-[#e1e1e1] mb-14 mt-4"
            ref={buttonElement}
          >
            {theFile ? (
              <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
                <span>
                  <img width="15" height="15" src="/file-form.svg" alt="" />
                </span>
                <span className="ml-1">{theFile?.name}</span>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <>
                <span className="text-blue-400 ">Add</span> or
                <span className="text-blue-400"> Drop</span> a file here
              </>
            )}
          </button>
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="submit"
            className="text-white text-lg rounded-[10px] py-[8px] px-2 mt-4 bg-[#008aff] w-[50%]"
          />
        </form>
      ) : (
        <div className="2xl:w-[20%] xl:w-[15%] lg:w-[10%] lg:py-0 py-8 flex items-center justify-center">
          <h2 className="font-light text-3xl text-center mt-8">
            Thank you for your submission!
          </h2>
        </div>
      )}
```

This is how I am getting the file in the s3 bucket.

[image]

Comment: Quick update,

So basically I was resetting the state in the handleChange by doing `setTheFile(null);`

This was actually resetting the file before it was uploaded to S3 and this is why i was only getting the name of the file with empty content.

Now I am facing another problem, basically if I click to upload a file named 'asd.png' and I send it, I will get an empty file the first time.

When I then try to upload a second file, for example let's say "fafa.txt", it will take this name, but instead of uploading the actualy "fafa.txt" file it actually uploads "asd.png" (the previous file)

Comment: ... i.e it uploads a file called "fafa.txt" which at first glance appears to be empty, but when I change the extension manually to "fafa.png" for example, I actually get the image (asd.png) which I uloaded previously?

Somehow it's taking the state of the previous file, the state of the name of the current file, combining them and uploading them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some debugging on my own end I managed to discover what was causing both problems.

The first problem which I had (receiving completely empty/blank files) was caused due to the fact that I was resetting the File state in the **handleChange()** func, all I had to do to resolve that problem was to remove the `setTheFile(null);` and this helped resolve one issue but created another.

The second issue which I started getting after this was, that the files which were being sent were taking a wrong state (i.e initially sending a file named 'asd.png', would send it blank, then on the second attempt of uploading a file named "example.txt", it would take the name of "example.txt", but it'd use the 'content' of "asd.png" and in the .txt file it'd render compiled image gibberish, changing the extension of the file named "example.txt" to "example.png" would actually render the image which I uploaded previously.

This was caused due to the fact that I was setting the state of the file in **handleChange()** via `setTheFile(event.target.files[0]);`

and then 2 lines below this I was trying to use "theFile" state.

So simply changing this from **handleChange()**

```
await axios.put(url, theFile, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': event.target.files[0].type,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    });
```

to

```
await axios.put(url, event.target.files[0], {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': event.target.files[0].type,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
});
```

resolved the second problem as well.